# How do I convert a string representing a signed hex int into its signed int Doubleword number in 80x86?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, hex, ascii

So I am taking an assembly language course and I am stuck on this problem from the book:
Using the windows 32 console (so I have an `io.h` to use), I am supposed to take a valid hex value inputted by the user and then display the actual hex value in the register `EAX`.  So if the user entered "AB CD E2 18", then after the procedure `EAX` would hold the value: `ABCDE218`.
The parts that I am stuck on are the `A`-`F` values.  If I use `A` for example, I can get the bits to read `00000010`, but I don't know how to change that into its hex value `A`.  Here is what I have so far:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.CODE

hexToInt    PROC
        push   ebp                 ; save base pointer
        mov    ebp, esp            ; establish stack frame
        sub    esp, 4              ; local space for sign
        push   ebx                 ; Save registers
        push   edx
        push   esi
        pushfd                     ; save flags

        mov    esi,[ebp+8]         ; get parameter (source addr)

WhileBlankD:
        cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],' '  ; space?
        jne    EndWhileBlankD      ; exit if not
        inc    esi                 ; increment character pointer
        jmp    WhileBlankD         ; and try again
EndWhileBlankD:

        mov    eax,1               ; default sign multiplier
IfPlusD:cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'+'  ; leading + ?
        je     SkipSignD           ; if so, skip over
IfMinusD:
        cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'-'  ; leading - ?
        jne    EndIfSignD          ; if not, save default +
        mov    eax,-1              ; -1 for minus sign
SkipSignD:
        inc    esi                 ; move past sign
EndIfSignD:

        mov    [ebp-4],eax         ; save sign multiplier
        mov    eax,0               ; number being accumulated

WhileDigitD:
        cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'0'  ; compare next character to '0'
        jb     EndWhileDigitD      ; not a digit if smaller than '0'
        cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'9'  ; compare to '9'
        ja     TestForHexD      
        mov    bl,[esi]            ; ASCII character to BL
        and    ebx,0000000Fh       ; convert to single-digit integer
        and    eax, ebx
        shl    eax, 4
        inc    esi
        jmp    WhileDigitD
TestForHexD:
        cmp    BYTE PTR [esi], 'F'
        ja     EndWhileDigitD
        mov    bl, [esi]
        sub    bl, 31h
        and    ebx, 000000FFh
        or     al, bl
        shl    eax, 4
        inc    esi                 ; increment character pointer
        jmp    WhileDigitD         ; go try next character
EndWhileDigitD:

; if value is < 80000000h, multiply by sign
        cmp    eax,80000000h       ; 80000000h?
        jnb    endIfMaxD           ; skip if not
        imul   DWORD PTR [ebp-4]   ; make signed number
endIfMaxD:

        popfd                      ; restore flags
        pop    esi                 ; restore registers
        pop    edx
        pop    ebx
        mov    esp, ebp            ; delete local variable space
        pop    ebp 
        ret                        ; exit
hexToInt    ENDP

        END
```

The `TestForHex` label is where I am trying to convert the ASCII string to hex. I was looking around and read that I could accomplish my goal by shifting and masking, but I can't figure it out and I can't find any examples.  At this point I am sure its something really small that I am just over looking, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some bugs in your code.

First, in **0 ... 9** string to integer conversion code, you don't do ASCII to binary conversion as you should do, but instead you do `and ebx,0Fh`, which is incorrect. You need to subtract `'0'` (`30h`) from each ASCII character, like this:

```
mov bl,[esi]
sub bl,'0' ; sub bl,30h
```

Then, also in **0 ... 9** string to integer conversion code:

```
and    eax, ebx
```

If the number consists of only 0...9 digits, `and eax, ebx` will produce always 0. It should be:

```
or al,bl
```

Then, you do `shl eax,4`, even if you don't know if there will be more digits. That means that the number will be 16 times bigger than it should.

Then, you give the example input with spaces, but your code does not handle spaces (`20h`) properly, it ends reading input for any value below `'0'` (`30h`), it seems to accept only leading spaces (skip this if you don't want to accept spaces in between).

So, the entire code block above should be:

```
WhileDigitD:
        cmp    byte ptr [esi], ' ' ; delete this if you don't want spaces in between.
        je     next_char           ; delete this if you don't want spaces in between.
        cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'0'  ; compare next character to '0'
        jb     EndWhileDigitD      ; not a digit if smaller than '0'
        cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'9'  ; compare to '9'
        ja     TestForHexD      
        mov    bl,[esi]            ; ASCII character to BL

        sub    bl,'0'              ; sub bl,30h -> convert ASCII to binary.

shift_eax_by_4_and_add_bl:
        shl    eax,4               ; shift the current value 4 bits to left.
        or     al,bl               ; add the value of the current digit.

next_char:
        inc    esi
        jmp    WhileDigitD
```

I also added labels `next_char` and `shift_eax_by_4_and_add_bl`. The reason for `next_char` should be evident, `shift_eax_by_4_and_add_bl` is to minimize duplicate code of 0...9 and A...F code blocks, see below.

You don't check that that the hexadecimal A...F digit is within range **A ... F**, only that it's **below or equal to F**. Otherwise it has same bug with `shl eax,4`. And as usually duplicate code should be avoided, I added `shift_eax_by_4_and_add_bl` label to minimize duplicate code.

So I think it should be:

**Edit:** corrected `sub bl,31h` -> `sub bl,('A'-0Ah)`.

```
TestForHexD:
        cmp    BYTE PTR [esi], 'A'
        jb     EndWhileDigitD
        cmp    BYTE PTR [esi], 'F'
        ja     EndWhileDigitD
        mov    bl,[esi]
        sub    bl,('A'-0Ah)         ; sub bl,55 -> convert ASCII to binary.
        jmp    shift_eax_by_4_and_add_bl
```

Comment: I like what you did with the first code block up there.  I would up vote it if I had more rep.  The TestForHexD code block though is still giving me the same problem.  It evaluates 'A' but when you sub bl, 31h, it just gives me 10h, and not Ah.  As I need all of this to fit into the EAX register, I need each Hex number to fit into a single bit.

Comment: @Seff Oh, the hardcoded subtraction constant `31h` was incorrect, I didn't notice that. As `A` should be `0Ah` in hexadecimal or `10` in decimal, the correct value to subtract is `('A' - 0Ah)`, that is `37h` in hexadecimal, `55` in decimal. In one bit you can fit only `0` or `1`, nothing more. One hexadecimal digit represents exactly one nibble (4 bits).

Comment: I figured it out!!  Looks like you were also missing the command:  `mov    bl,[esi]` for the TestForHexD: code block.  Just added that and it fixed everything.  Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: @Seff You're welcome. You're right, I had forgotten the `mov bl,[esi]` instruction by mistake, so I added it to my answer too.

Comment: AND with `0xf` is a valid way to convert ASCII `'0'..'9'` to integer `0..9`.  Their ASCII codes range from `0x30 .. 0x39`, so keeping the low 4 bits is perfectly valid if you've already ruled out non-decimal-digit characters, and gives identical results to `c - '0'`.  Subtraction is easier to understand, and can be done as *part* of checking for 0..9 vs. a..f, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert a character (for simplicity, say, in upper case) representing a hex digit into the value of that digit you need to do this:

```
IF char >= 'A'
  value = char - 'A' + 10
ELSE
  value = char - '0'
ENDIF
```

If you need to do the reverse, you do the reverse:

```
IF value >= 10
  char = value - 10 + 'A'
ELSE
  char = value + '0'
ENDIF
```

Here you exploit the fact that the ASCII characters `0` through `9` have consecutive ASCII codes and so do the ASCII characters `A` through `F`.