# Assembly x86 - String Representation of Hex Value

Tags: c, string, assembly, hex, ascii

I have a cookie with the value `0x2486651c` and the instructions I was given are

> You will need to include a string representation of your cookie in your exploit string. The string should consist of the eight hexadecimal digits (ordered from most to least significant) without a leading "0x"

Then the second instruction is

> Recall that a string is represented in C as a sequence of bytes followed by a byte with value 0. Type "man ascii" on any Linux machine to see the byte representations of the characters you need.

The exploit string they are referring to is a text file containing hex converted into a `raw` file with the command `./hex2raw <filename> raw`

I think it is the second instruction giving me trouble. When it says we need to see the `byte representations of the characters you need` I'm not sure what it means by that. For example the second byte of our string `86` has no conversion on the table produced from the command `man ascii`.

Any ideas on what the string representation is for our cookie?

Comment: 0x86 is not valid ascii

Comment: @Dani Agreed, hence my confusion...

Comment: Just create an exploit string that includes these eight characters: `2486651c`

Comment: I think what it is asking is to convert 0x2486651c to the string `2486651c` which would be these HEX values 0x32 0x34 0x38 0x36 0x36 0x35 0x31 0x63

Comment: @MichaelPetch I think your right, I need it in little endian byte ordering. Would that be the right order?

Comment: It does say _ordered from **most to least** significant_ which suggests to me that it wants it in order that they appear in 0x2486651c . Most significant nibble (4 bits) is the `2` and then `4`, `8`, `6`, `6`, `5`, `1`, `c`  (`c` being least significant nibble)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for your help, got it working by converting to the hex string to those hex values

Comment: With ASCII strings the endianness is ignored, always store them per byte from beginning to end, so 5th char is at +4 offset (first is at +0). You don't normally access part of C string by word/dword (except some crazy performance tricks, where you should know what you are doing), that's why endianness is not applied to them.

Comment: Take a look to that post [How do I convert a string representing a signed hex int into its signed int Doubleword number in 80x86?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047113/how-do-i-convert-a-string-representing-a-signed-hex-int-into-its-signed-int-doub) which is doing the reverse function.