# Intel x86 NASM: Convert terminal-input

Tags: x86, nasm

I´m trying to get an input from the terminal, when starting the program (e.g. ./exec 1234ABCDE). It has 9 letters/numbers and I have to cut that input in blocks of three, multiply it and add everything together. The letters stand for numbers: A = 10; B = 11; C = 12 and so on.
(1*7) + (2*3) + (3*1) + (4*7) + ([A]10*3) + ([B]11*1) + ... = 222
After that I need the last digit of the sum (in this case the 2). 
I hope you get what I need to do.

```
global main
extern printf

segment .data
printausweisnummer: db "Ausweisnummer: ",0
printnr: db "%d", 0
enter: db "",10,0

segment .text

main:
push printausweisnummer
call printf
add esp,4

mov eax, esp        
add eax, 8
mov eax, [eax]       
add eax, 4
mov eax, [eax]              

add eax, 9
mov DWORD [eax],0
sub eax, 9
push eax
call printf
add esp,4
push enter
call printf
add esp,4
```

Everything is fine until this point. I just print out the input.

```
mov eax, esp        
add eax, 8
mov eax, [eax]       
add eax, 4
mov eax, [eax]              

;-----
```

Now here I need to take -in this case- 'E'  and get the number 14 to add it on to a register. (ASCII E -> 69; 69 - 55 = 14) But when calling printf eax here it just prints out "1234ABCDE".

Does anybody have a solution how I get the ASCII Code of the 'E' to convert it to the Integer 14?

(Then take the next one (D) and multiply it with 3 and so on...)

```
end:
push enter
call printf
add esp,4
```

Comment: Why not just `mov eax, [esp+8]` / `mov eax, [eax+4]` like a normal person?  There's no point to spending extra instructions calculating an address in another register before the first load.  Anyway, that gives you a pointer to a string, and then you need to do hex -> int on it in chunks of 3 characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string representing a signed hex int into its signed int Doubleword number in 80x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16047113) but I'd rather find a question with a more efficient answer.  BTW, the encoding you describe (A..F = 10..15) is extremely well known, and is called hexadecimal.  It's the standard way of representing base 16 (4 bits per digit) in ASCII.  Oh, but you're not multiplying by the normal place value, just by 1, 2, and 3 instead of 16^0, 16^1, and 16^2.

Comment: @PeterCordes I already changed the code to mov eax, [esp+8] / mov eax, [eax+4] before, but it doesn´t work and gives me an error (segmentation fault/memory access error (i don´t know what it´s called in english)).